# python networkx - problem with Persian characters

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

Why output of this graph doesn't show correct string?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge("محمد رضا","رضایی زاده حسین")
nx.draw(G,encoding='utf-8', with_labels=True)
plt.savefig("path.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Very nice minimal working example.

The labels are being clipped by the bounding box of the plot. 
If you increase the axis x-limits, they should be fine.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge("محمد رضا","رضایی زاده حسین")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
nx.draw(G,encoding='utf-8', with_labels=True, ax=ax)
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
dx = xlim[1]-xlim[0]
ax.set_xlim(xlim[0]-0.1*dx, xlim[1]+0.1*dx)
plt.savefig("path.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first install these packages:

```
pip install arabic-reshaper
pip install python-bidi
```

code for fix Persian/Arabic texts:

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

text = "رضایی زاده حسین"
reshaped_text = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(text))
```